# How to get results after line break using regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a log file and following data occurrence but I want very last data and want to comment in our system.

```
2018-07-25 10:38:33.711503-0700 0x287f4  0x0    119    0    checked: [version:default] Server task 0x1013e3620: checked sentence: 'call to test 1', {
"is_device" = 0;
"is_call" = 0;
"is_system" = 0;
"is_time_out" = 0;
out = "check server data";
```

}

Now here, I am using regex javascript but I am only getting data till

```
2018-07-25 10:38:33.711503-0700 0x287f4  0x0    119    0    checked: [version:default] Server task 0x1013e3620: checked sentence: 'call to test 1', {
```

And its not giving me output of everything and I tried \n.*, \r.*, [\s\S]* in my regex but nothing works.

Here is my code,

```
var CheckedRegex = new RegExp(/.*(checked sentence.*)/)
var CheckingArray = new Array()
var LastChecked = ""
var matched = 0

function scan(doc) {
  var found = ""
  if(found = doc.text.match(CheckedRegex)) {
    CheckingArray.push(found)
    LastChecked = found
    matched++
  }
}

function comment() {
  if(matched) {
    return LastChecked[0]
    }
```

Output:

```
2018-07-25 10:38:33.711503-0700 0x287f4  0x0    119    0    checked: [version:default] Server task 0x1013e3620: checked sentence: 'call to test 1', {
```

Expected:

```
    2018-07-25 10:38:33.711503-0700 0x287f4  0x0    119    0    checked: [version:default] Server task 0x1013e3620: checked sentence: 'call to test 1', {
    "is_device" = 0;
    "is_call" = 0;
    "is_system" = 0;
    "is_time_out" = 0;
    voice = "check server data";
}
```

Any idea what's missing?

Comment: Try it with [multiline flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/multiline).

Answer (score 0):

One option is

```
^.+checked sentence[^}]+}
```

Match the beginning of a line, followed by characters (not including newline characters), followed by `checked sentence`, followed by characters *including* newline characters until a `}` is reached.

```js
const re = /^.+checked sentence[^}]+}/m;
const text = `text
more text
    2018-07-25 10:38:33.711503-0700 0x287f4  0x0    119    0    checked: [version:default] Server task 0x1013e3620: checked sentence: 'call to test 1', {
    "is_device" = 0;
    "is_call" = 0;
    "is_system" = 0;
    "is_time_out" = 0;
    voice = "check server data";
}`;
console.log(text.match(re));
```

https://regex101.com/r/We6iQL/1

Also, there's no need for `new RegExp` - if you can type in a regular expression literal, just do that, eg

```
var CheckedRegex = /^.+checked sentence[^}]+}/m
```

Comment: This solution is also not working. It says result not found.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex `.*(checked sentence.*)` matches only the first line because the [dot](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) does not match a line break character.

You could match the date like pattern for your example, then match any character using `[\S\S]*?` and make it non greedy using `?`.

Then match `checked sentence` followed by matching not a `}` using a negated character class `[^}]+` followed by matching `}`

[`^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[\s\S]*?checked sentence[^}]+}`](https://regex101.com/r/Ey2bNZ/1/)

```
var CheckedRegex = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[\s\S]*?checked sentence[^}]+}/gm;
```

```js
var CheckedRegex = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[\s\S]*?checked sentence[^}]+}/gm;
var string = `test

2018-07-25 10:38:33.711503-0700 0x287f4  0x0    119    0    checked: [version:default] Server task 0x1013e3620: checked sentence: 'call to test 1', {
    "is_device" = 0;
    "is_call" = 0;
    "is_system" = 0;
    "is_time_out" = 0;
    out = "check server data";
}
test

2018-07-25 10:38:33.711503-0700 0x287f4  0x0    119    0    checked: [version:default] Server task 0x1013e3620: checked sentence: 'call to test 1', {
        "is_device" = 0;
        "is_call" = 0;
        "is_system" = 0;
        "is_time_out" = 0;
        voice = "check server data";
    } 


2018-07-25 10:38:33.711503-0700 0x287f4  0x0    119    0    checked: [version:default] Server task 0x1013e3620: checked sentence: 'call to test 1', {
        "is_device" = 0;
        "is_call" = 0;
        "is_system" = 0;
        "is_time_out" = 0;
        voice = "check server data";
    }

2018-07-25 10:38:33.711503-0700 0x287f4 0x0 119 0 checked: [version:default] Server task 0x1013e3620: checked sentence: 'call to test 1', { "is_device" = 0; "is_call" = 0; "is_system" = 0; "is_time_out" = 0; voice = "check server data"; }


2018-07-25 10:38:33.711503-0700 0x287f4 0x0 119 0 checked: [version:default] Server task 0x1013e3620: checked sentence: 'call to test 1', { "is_device" = 0; "is_call" = 0; "is_system" = 0; "is_time_out" = 0; voice = "check server data"; }`;
console.log(string.match(CheckedRegex));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working. It says no result found.

Comment: @KD228 What do you see when you run `console.log(doc.text.match(CheckedRegex))`

Comment: after looking it further, the style of following data is same but values are different depend on the case so I can't hardcore the values. 2018-07-25 10:38:33.711503-0700 0x287f4  0x0    119    0    checked: [version:default] Server task 0x1013e3620: checked sentence: 'call to test 1', {
        "is_device" = 0;
        "is_call" = 0;
        "is_system" = 0;
        "is_time_out" = 0;
        voice = "check server data";
    }

Comment: @KD228 I have updated my answer. Can you check if that works for you?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response but it just empty report for var CheckedRegex = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[\s\S]*?checked sentence[^}]+}/gm;

Comment: And if you test it without the leading `^`?  Like `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[\s\S]*?checked sentence[^}]+}`

Comment: Same thing. I think for some reason its not getting a results from line 2. I'll ask our devs to look into it. Thanks!